# Save JSON data from API endpoint to database in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby on Rails and I'm building a web-app where I am receiving data via an API. I am able to get the data from the API endpoint, but I am not sure how to go about saving the JSON data to the rails database from what I have done so far.

Under the method events I've tried to save the data from the parsed json, but nothing is saving.

Below is the JSON and model:

{"Code"=>"AAPL", "Name"=>"Apple Inc" }

model Market symbol:string Name:string

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'
require 'json'
require 'rest-client' 


class Market < ApplicationRecord 
  include HTTParty
  base_uri "eodhistoricaldata.com/"

  def data
    self.class.get('/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=[redacted]&filter=General&limit&fmt=json')
  end

  def data2
    self.class.get('/api/eod/AAPL.US?api_token=[redacted]&fmt=json&filter=last_close')
  end

  def events
    data.parsed_response
  end

  def create
    result = RestClient.get('https://www.eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=[redacted]&filter=General&limit&fmt=json')
    parsed_json = JSON.parse(result)
    Market.create(
    symbol: parsed_json['Code'],
    name: parsed_json['Name']
  )
  Market.save
  end

end
```

Comment: Please add your error to your question. Also, if `data` is literally `{"Code"=>"AAPL", "Name"=>"Apple Inc" }`, then your code doesn't make any sense because iterating a hash (your essentially doing `{"Code"=>"AAPL", "Name"=>"Apple Inc" }.each`) is going to give you key value pairs, not another hash.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `parsed_json` is in fact

```
{"Code"=>"AAPL", "Name"=>"Apple Inc"}
```

Then:

```
def create
  result      = RestClient.get('https://www.eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=[redacted]&filter=General&limit&fmt=json')
  parsed_json = JSON.parse(result)
  self.symbol = parsed_json['symbol']
  self.name   = parsed_json['name']
  save!
end
```

... isn't going to save anything because `parsed_json` has neither of the keys `symbol` nor `name`. It has `Code` and `Name`. It seems like you should try:

```
def create
  result      = RestClient.get('https://www.eodhistoricaldata.com/api/fundamentals/AAPL.US?api_token=[redacted]&filter=General&limit&fmt=json')
  parsed_json = JSON.parse(result)
  update(
    symbol: parsed_json['Code'],
    name:   parsed_json['Name']
  )
end
```